# jQuery overriding checkbox behavior

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, jquery-animate, css-animations

I'm currently using a checkbox to perform css animations for my sidenav. I have the checkbox attached to my hamburger and upon which it is in the checked state, I have corresponding css changes to the sidenav.

Here's the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sidebar_toggler" name="name" value="">
  <div class="page-wrap">
    <label for="sidebar_toggler"><img src="./images/hamburger.png" class="hamburger"></label>
```

Here's the CSS (Sass) animation for this bit:

```
#sidebar_toggler
  display: none

  &checked + .page-wrap

    .sidebar
      left: 0px

    .hamburger
      left: 200px

    .text_elements
       margin-left: 90px
```

This part works beautifully, however, when I click on a link in the sidebar, I need to reposition the .sidebar, .hamburger and .text_elements (or in essence close the sidebar and move back the surrounding elements).

I tried doing another checkbox for the links, however, I don't think my website likes having multiple checkboxes on the same page. I also tried setting jQuery on the sidebar links, but that only works once. After I click on the link in the sidebar, all subsequent clicks to the hamburger only adjusts the .text_elements position, and stops opening the sidenav.

Here's the code for the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#side_links').on('click', function() {
    $('.sidebar').css({
    'left': '-190px'
    });
  });

  $('#side_links').on('click', function() {
    $('.hamburger').css({
    'left': '20px'
    });
  });

});
```

Some help?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's the jfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Lad2s4yd/1/), not sure why the jquery's not working here, had to strip down my code to provide you with the gist of what's going on...

Comment: The jQuery isn't working because you didn't select a version of jQuery from the `Javascript` popup.

Comment: Got it, it's updated, now the the fiddle represents my problem

Comment: What's the link to the updated fiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/Lad2s4yd/1

Comment: That's the same link as before. It still doesn't have jQuery loaded.

Comment: I updated the same jfiddle with jquery (2.1.3) loaded...

Comment: When you update a fiddle it gives it a new URL. The last number increments, so it should change to /2.

Comment: my bad: https://jsfiddle.net/Lad2s4yd/5/

Comment: The problem is that clicking on a sidebar link closes the sidebar, but it doesn't uncheck the checkbox, so the CSS for `&checked` is still in effect.

Comment: @barmar that makes sense, I figure the fix would be adding jquery to set the checkbox value to false on click of the link but still getting same behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/Lad2s4yd/20/

Answer (score 0):

Since your opening of the sidebar is based on whether `#sidebar` is checked, all you have to do is uncheck it to close the the sidebar. The CSS will then take care of the rest.

```js
$('#side_links').on('click', function() {
  $("#sidebar_toggler").prop('checked', false)
});
```

```css
.contents {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -190px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 0;
  font-family: Offside;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.sidebar li {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

#sidebar_toggler {
  display: none;
}

#sidebar_toggler:checked + .page-wrap .sidebar {
  left: 0px;
}

#sidebar_toggler:checked + .page-wrap .hamburger {
  left: 200px;
}

#sidebar_toggler:checked + .page-wrap .text_elements {
  margin-left: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="sidebar_toggler">
<div class="page-wrap">
  <label for="sidebar_toggler"><img src="./images/hamburger.png" class="hamburger"></label>
  <div id="contents">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="splash">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="text_elements">
          <div class="container-fluid" id="project_header">
            <a name="projects"></a>
            <p>Text elements here</p>
            <h1 id="projects_h1">Projects</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Sidebar begins -->
  <div class="sidebar">
    <nav class="link_effect">
      <ul>
        <li id="side_links"><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Github</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```